# What did Lord Ram tried to Teach?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama

I have heard many times that Lord Vishnu's incarnation as Lord Ram was to teach people how to live life. But it is not possible for me to understand this.

Could any one Please help me in understanding the exact teaching of Lord Ram.

Comment: Rama took birth as an Human and made himself surrender in front his own maya (unlike Krishna) like all other humans. He did that surrender so that He can also feel sadness, anger and all other emotions that all humans use to feel. He wanted to set an example that If a person has faith in his dharma and keep going on journey of life by performing all of his duties and then Dharma itself started to support him and he can even take victory on ruler of all three loks (worlds) with ease. Live life without greed and have complete faith in Lord then You will never loose in life like Rama didn't loose

Comment: He also taught us many things during his life span which can be learn by reading Ramayana. If you wanna learn his teaching then you can follow my instagram account in which I use to show Lord Rama's views and Ramayana's teaching/lessons. Here is my ID "rbh.sharmaa". Ramayana is full of fruitful thoughts.

Comment: Besides once Shiva himself said that when some asked why Narayana takes birth, then he gave some points and at last he said there are also some reasons which can't be understand by anyone because its not easy to understand full reason behind any karma of Lord Narayana. It is not possible for me (Shiva) also to fully understand Narayana.

Comment: Thank you @Rishabh for your answer. This is what I was searching but people told me to read Ramayana and verse. and marked it as duplicate.